# Adding a new property to an Object that exists in an Array, using .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, babeljs

I'm trying to conditionally add a property to an object in an array using .map(), but I seem to be missing something. My array of objects remains unchanged after the map is complete. All of this is the result of trying to resolve the ESLint error 'no-param-reassign' if that helps understand why I'm doing this.

I've made a rudimentary example of what I'm trying to accomplish here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osggvxvm/7/).

```
var aList = [{
    Title: "Enders Game",
    Rating: 8
  },
  {
    Title: "Harry Potter",
    Rating: 10
  }];

console.log('before', aList);

aList.map(function(book) {
    if(book.Title == "Enders Game"){
    console.log({ ...book, completed: true })
    return { ...book, completed: true };
  }
  console.log({ ...book, completed: false })
  return { ...book, completed: false };
});

console.log('after', aList);
```

Comment: `.map()` doesn't mutate the original. It creates a new Array, which is returned, so `var newMap = aList.map(...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because you are not using the result of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var aList = [{ Title: "Enders Game", Rating: 8 }, { Title: "Harry Potter", Rating: 10 }];

aList.forEach(function(book) {
    book.completed = book.Title == "Enders Game";
});

console.log(aList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For an all new array, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and **use** the result of it. For adding a new property to an object, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which mutates and returns the object at the first parameter.

```js
var aList = [{ Title: "Enders Game", Rating: 8 }, { Title: "Harry Potter", Rating: 10 }],
    newList = aList.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, {completed: book.Title == "Enders Game"}));

console.log(aList);
console.log(newList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, it could be written much cleaner and readable in that way.

```
  const aList = [{ Title: 'Enders Game', Rating: 8 }, { Title: 'Harry Potter', Rating: 10 }];
  const newList = aList.map((book) => (
    {
      ...book,
      completed: book.Title === 'Enders Game',
    }));
```